# Programmatically turn off the screen partially in android

Tags: android, screen

Is it possible to turn off the screen partially in android phones (while keeping other part active)? Using NDK? Does anyone have  experience doing it?

Explanation: I want to keep the full system running in partial display while keeping other part off. For example- For Galaxy nexus with 720x1280 screen, I want to use 720x320 and want to turn off rest 720x960 pixels. How can I approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example- galaxy nexus has 720x1280 display. I want to use upper 720x320 and want to turn off rest 720x960 pixels... is that possible?

No, sorry. You are welcome to not draw in the bottom half of the screen, but it cannot be "turned off".

Comment: @Morison: It is physically impossible from a hardware standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look on [PowerManger](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) class. There is no need to use  NDK.

Comment: Thanks @Yuvi for your answer. That class only tuns off/on or partially awakes the system. However, what I want is to turn off half the screen while keep the other part running. For example- galaxy nexus has 720x1280 display. I want to use upper 720x320 and want to turn off rest 720x960 pixels... is that possible?

Comment: @Morison maybe because those pixels are already turned off: [Quora: black pixels or turned off?](https://www.quora.com/Why-are-black-lit-pixels-in-LED-displays-not-turned-off) Research the topic for more.